# Implementing a quota system to limit requests in a web based app

Tags: mysql, go, redis, memcached, quota

I want to limit my users to 25k/requests per hour/day/whatever.

My first idea was to simply use mysql and have a column in the users table where i would store the requests and i would increment this counter each time the user makes a request. Problem with this approach is that sometimes you end up writing at the same time in the column and you get a deadlock from mysql, so this isn't really a good way to go about it, is it ?

Another way would be, instead of incrementing the counters of a column, to insert log records in a separate table and then count these records for a given timespan, but this way you can easily end up with million records table and the query can be too slow.

When using a RDBMS another aspect to take into consideration is that at each request you'd have to count the user quota from database and this can take time depending on either of the above mentioned methods.

My second idea, i thought using something like redis/memcached (not sure of alternatives or which one of them is faster) and store the request counters there. This would be fast enough to query and increment the counters, for sure faster than a RDBMS, but i haven't tried it with huge amounts of data, so i am not sure how it will perform just yet.

My third idea, i would keep the quota data in memory in a map, something like `map[int]int` where the key would be the user_id and the value would be the quota usage and i'd protect the map access with a mutex. This would be the fastest solution of all but then what do you do if for some reason your app crashes, you lose all that data related to the number of requests certain user did. One way would be to catch the app when crashing and loop through the map and update the database. Is this feasible?

Not sure if either of the above is the right approach, but i am open to suggestions.

Comment: Since you're talking about a web app, one straightforward and significantly more lightweight solution is to do this with HAProxy, which has optimized memory structures for holding large numbers of counters, and I believe is [the way Stack Exchange does its rate limiting](http://blog.serverfault.com/2010/08/26/1016491873/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "get a deadlock from mysql" when you try to update a row at the same time.  But a simple `update rate_limit set count = count + 1 where user_id = ?` should do what you want.

Personally I have had great success with Redis for doing rate limiting.  There are lots of resources out there to help you understand the appropriate approach for your use case.  Here is one I just glanced at that seems to handle things correctly: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/introduction-to-rate-limiting-with-redis/155.  Using pipelines (`MULTI`) or Lua scripts may make things even nicer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i don't have the exact error code at hand atm, but the problem arises when we do parallel requests and it happens that 2 or more requests try to update that column at the same time, so then your example will fail. I think there needs to be a way to do atomic updates, but haven't found any. 

Thanks for the redis link, i'll have a look at it.

Comment: @Twisted1919 that's not what a deadlock is.  Atomic updates are fine, and lock contention is handled transparently. Deadlocks occur when two transactions each try to acquire a lock that the other one already holds, which isn't going to happen in a simple atomic update of one column in one row.

Answer (score 0):

You can persist your `map[int]int` in RDBMS or just file system time to time and in defer function. You even can use it as cache instead of redis. Surely it will be anyway faster than connection to third-party service every request. Also you can store counters on user side simply in cookies. Smart user can clear cookies of-douse but is it so dangerous at all and you can also provide some identification info in cookies to make clearing uncomfortable.